# Reference string value in VF controller

Tags: visualforce

In my controller, I have:

```
public Contact c {get; set;}
public Contact cont {get; set;}
Public String acc3{get;set;}
Public String acc2{get;set;}

public controller(){

 acc3 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Master_Id__c'); 
           if(acc3 != null)        
            {
                this.c= [   SELECT  Master_Id__c
                              FROM    Contact
                              WHERE   Master_Id__c = : acc3 ];  
            }
              else
            {this.c= new Contact  ();} 

 acc2 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('LastName'); 
           if(acc2 != null)        
            {
                this.cont= [   SELECT  LastName
                              FROM    Contact
                              WHERE   LastName = : acc2 ];  
            }
               else
            {this.cont=  new Contact(ReportsTo=new contact(Master_Id__c='xxxx')); } 
}
```

For string acc2, in the else statement, I have hardcoded the value to 'xxxx'. However, I want that value to be the same as the string in acc3 (which is an input field in my VF page). So it would look something like (Master_Id__c='!acc3')); 
However, I can't seem to get the syntax for it correctly.
Any suggestions on how to correctly reference the string acc3?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That usually works, but for some reason it did not work in this case. (This code was to insert a parent and child at the same time. A parent contact with a child as well).

What finally worked was when I moved the this.cont into the Save function and changed it to

```
{this.cont=  new Contact(ReportsTo=new contact(Master_Id__c=c.Master_Id__c)); }
```

before insert

Answer (score 2):

As this is just Apex code, you can reference the string directly:

```
{this.cont=  new Contact(ReportsTo=new contact(Master_Id__c=acc3)); }
```

As you create the new instance of Contact, you are assigning the string variable acc3 to the Contact object's Master_Id__c field.

The `{! }` syntax is only used in Visualforce pages not Apex classes.